# Nested For each inside Do while in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My vba script here is pulling filenames from a specified folder in variable: `path`, and attempting to sort through them highlighting the most up to date files.

The files are formatted as such: `folderpath\filename[issue].extension` with the issue being what we use to determine how up to date the part is. Currently what I want my script to do is seperate the filename and issue into two seperate variables, check `MyCollection` for whether the filename already exists, and if it does, whether it is the most up to date issue. The end goal of the script is to sort through a large folder of these files and be left with only the ones that have the highest issue

Currently my script has a nested `For Each i in MyCollection` running inside the `Do While Len(Filename) > 0`. When I remove the nested part, it iterates over all files inside a folder, but when it is included, it only iterates over two. What is the cause of this? I cannot seem to figure it out

Ignore most of the msgboxes, they're just me trying to figure out what the codes up to

```
Private Function PullUpdatedFileNames(Path As String) As Collection

Dim MyCollection As New Collection
Dim Filename As String
Dim TotalFiles As Integer

Dim PartName As String
Dim Issue As String

Dim CollectionFileName As String
Dim iValue As Integer

Filename = Dir(Path & "\")

 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    If InStr(Filename, "[") > 0 And InStr(Filename, "]") > 0 Then
        PartName = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, "[") - 1) & Right(Filename, InStr(Filename, "]") + 1)
        Issue = Mid(Filename, InStr(Filename, "[") + 1, InStr(Filename, "]") - InStr(Filename, "[") - 1)
        If MyCollection.Count <> 0 Then

            For Each i In MyCollection
                MsgBox "Start for each loop" & vbNewLine & "Line being searched:" & vbNewLine & i
                CollectionFileName = Right(Dir(i), Len(i) - Len(Path))
                If Left(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") - 1) & Right(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "]") + 1) = PartName Then
                    If Mid(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") + 1, InStr(CollectionFileName, "]") - InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") - 1) > Issue Then
                        MsgBox Filename & vbNewLine & "Not Added, Old part newer issue"
                    Else
                        MsgBox Filename & vbNewLine & "Added, This part was newer issue"
                        iValue = IndexOf(MyCollection, i)
                        MyCollection.Add Path & "\" & Filename
                        MyCollection.Remove iValue
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox Filename & vbNewLine & "Added New"
                    MyCollection.Add Path & "\" & Filename
                End If
            Next i

        Else
            MsgBox Filename & vbNewLine & "Added New"
            MyCollection.Add Path & "\" & Filename
        End If
        MsgBox Filename & " Added"
        TotalFiles = TotalFiles + 1
    Else
        MsgBox Filename & " Not Added"
    End If
    Filename = Dir
Loop

MsgBox TotalFiles & " file(s) selected within folder"

Set PullFileNames = MyCollection

End Function
```

Comment: Dir use a internal state and cannot be used twice (the second time you erase the first settings)

Comment: That's why it cannot be used to recursively parse folders

Comment: The issue is you use `dir` in this line `CollectionFileName = Right(Dir(i), Len(i) - Len(Path))` again.

Comment: When I remove the `For Each` section it iterates through each folder? Are you talking about Dir referring back to itself when it loops a second time, or when I used Dir(i) a bit earlier in the script? - just saw that Pᴇʜ

Comment: If I wanted to get the filename from a directory, what other method is there?

Comment: Okay, figured a solution - thanks for the help. Replaced the old line with this: `CollectionFileName = Right(i, Len(i) - InStrRev(i, "\"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who wants my final code, here it is

I've changed a few other things regarding how it was sorting through the files and deciding which ones to delete, point is that it works properly now

Thanks for the help

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ParentFolder As String
Dim UpdatedFiles As New Collection
Dim myfso As New FileSystemObject
Dim DeletedFiles As Integer

Dim exists As Boolean

Set fldrpicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldrpicker
    .Title = "Select Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Skip = True
        If Not Skip Then ParentFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
If IsEmpty(ParentFolder) Then GoTo Empt

Set updatefiles = PullUpdatedFileNames(ParentFolder)

Filename = Dir(ParentFolder & "\")

Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    For Each x In updatefiles
'        MsgBox "Stored Memory: " & x & vbNewLine & "File Read:         " & ParentFolder & "\" & Filename
        If ParentFolder & "\" & Filename = x Then
            exists = True
            GoTo skipthisif
        Else
            exists = False
        End If
    Next x
skipthisif:
    If exists = False Then myfso.DeleteFile ParentFolder & "\" & Filename
    If exists = False Then DeletedFiles = DeletedFiles + 1
    Filename = Dir
Loop

MsgBox DeletedFiles & " File(s) deleted from folder"

'ErrHandler:
'MsgBox "Copy error: " & File & vbNewLine & "A File could not be sorted in the source folder "
'Resume Next

GoTo scriptEnd

Empt:
MsgBox "Folder is empty"

scriptEnd:

End Sub

Private Function PullUpdatedFileNames(Path As String) As Collection

Dim MyCollection As New Collection
Dim Filename As String
Dim TotalFiles As Integer

Dim PartName As String
Dim Issue As String

Dim CollectionFileName As String
Dim iValue As Integer

Filename = Dir(Path & "\")

Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    If InStr(Filename, "[") > 0 And InStr(Filename, "]") > 0 Then
        PartName = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, "[") - 1) & Right(Filename, InStr(Filename, "]") + 1)
        Issue = Mid(Filename, InStr(Filename, "[") + 1, InStr(Filename, "]") - InStr(Filename, "[") - 1)
        If MyCollection.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each i In MyCollection
                CollectionFileName = Right(i, Len(i) - InStrRev(i, "\"))
                If Left(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") - 1) & Right(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "]") + 1) = PartName Then
                    If Mid(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") + 1, InStr(CollectionFileName, "]") - InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") - 1) > Issue Then
                        GoTo nextiteration
                    Else
'                        MsgBox Left(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") - 1) & Right(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "]") + 1) & vbNewLine & PartName
'                        MsgBox Mid(CollectionFileName, InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") + 1, InStr(CollectionFileName, "]") - InStr(CollectionFileName, "[") - 1) & vbNewLine & Issue
                        iValue = IndexOf(MyCollection, i)
                        MyCollection.Add Path & "\" & Filename
                        MyCollection.Remove iValue
                        GoTo nextiteration
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            MyCollection.Add Path & "\" & Filename
        Else
            MyCollection.Add Path & "\" & Filename
        End If

nextiteration:
        TotalFiles = TotalFiles + 1
    Else
    End If
    Filename = Dir
Loop

MsgBox TotalFiles & " file(s) recognised within folder"

Set PullUpdatedFileNames = MyCollection

End Function

Public Function IndexOf(ByVal coll As Collection, ByVal item As Variant) As Long
    Dim z As Long
    For z = 1 To coll.Count
        If coll(z) = item Then
            IndexOf = z
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```